# SQL Syntax error in python MySQL - query successful in MySQL workbench

Tags: python, mysql, sql, workbench

Dealing with something very annoying here. I'm writing a library DBMS in python and I have a function that creates a SQL statement by string interpolation. Plan to shift it to parametrized queries later.

The SQL statement generated works in MySQL Workbench. However,it gives me a syntax error in code. Here is the relevant code:

```
        def borrowDocument(self, doctype, doc_id, book_id, data):
            # if copies > 0 documents + decrement copies
            sql = dbcfg.sql['getDocDetails'].replace('{_id}', str(doc_id))
            logger.info("borrowDocument getDocDetails SQL: " + sql)
            try:
                self.cursor.execute(sql)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error in getting document details: " + str(e) + traceback.format_exc())
                sys.exit(-1)
```

The SQL I receive as a result of debugging code is :

`SELECT * from Librarian.Documents WHERE Doc_Id = 3;`

Which works in the MySQL workbench tool [as seen here!][1]

My data types seem to be correct too: [this is the setup of the Documents Table][2]

Any help would be appreciated! Spent a bit too long on this now. Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgAAD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47G4m.png

Edit: Added the actual error as requested, does not show me where the error is in the SQL:

```
22:52:39 :: ERROR : root: Error in getting document details: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * from Librarian.Documents WHERE Doc_Id = 3;"' at line 1Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 565, in cmd_query
    self._cmysql.query(
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * from Librarian.Documents WHERE Doc_Id = 3;"' at line 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\Projects\IntegratedLibrarySystem\app.py", line 186, in borrowDocument
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\rushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 279, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rushi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 573, in cmd_query
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * from Librarian.Documents WHERE Doc_Id = 3;"' at line 1
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It's very case based, I could send the entire project onto here

Comment: Please publish the syntax error in full.

Comment: Done! It's from my logs but its the exception message

Comment: Your SQL statement is surrounded by double-quotes.  I can't tell from your code who is putting them in, but that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the error indeed